# Delphi exe setup in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I have a multiple exe file in that was created in delphi 6 . I want to create a setup file from the Visual Studio 2010 for these EXE. How can i do that. Please provide me the steps for do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This still applies even though it's VS 2005 - setup projects haven't changed.

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/

The fact that it's a delhpi exe doesn't matter. To get it installed you just use the setup project's IDE, the File System on Target Machine view and drag/drop the exe into (usually) the Applcation Folder.

It may have dependencies that need to be installed - is that likely?